# Create worksheets object from string

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create and object of worksheets that I can iterate through. If I declare it like this, it **works**:

```
Set deptSheets = Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"))
```

Instead of explicit comma separated strings, I'd like to feed it a string (let's call it myStringOfSheets) variable that has the same content: `"Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3".`

Just swapping it out for a string `Set deptSheets = Sheets(Array(myStringOfSheets))` doesn't work because Array() is expecting explicit parameters. I've tried quite a few things, but I'm not having any success if anyone has any ideas please let me know.

```
Function deptSheets() As Object
    deptSheetsStr = Chr(34) & "Sheet1" & Chr(34) & "," & _
            Chr(34) & "Sheet2" & Chr(34) & "," & _
            Chr(34) & "Sheet3" & Chr(34)
    
   'Set deptSheets = Sheets(deptSheetsStr) <-- also does not work 
    Set deptSheets = Sheets(Split(deptSheetsStr, ",")) 'subscript out of range error on this line

End Function
```

Comment: `Set deptSheets = Sheets(Split("Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3", ", "))`

Comment: yeah I can do that but I'd much prefer to set the Sheets with the variable not a manually typed out list of sheet names. I want to be able to do something like `Set deptSheets = Sheets(sheetArray)` but I get a subscript out of range error

Comment: This is just an example. Replace the hard-coded string with your variable. The key part is `Split`.

Comment: You may have to do some `Replace`ing and maybe `Trim$` too to remove extra quotes and spaces.

Comment: `deptSheetsStr = "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"` does not compile.

Comment: you're right sorry I've fixed in question - I was quickly trying to sanitize the sample code from what I'm actually doing and pasted the wrong block.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works. I think the issue was I was declaring deptSheets as an OBJECT not Sheets and likely that my deptSheetsStr was malformed. For some reason I needed to create a separate array - I couldn't get it to work just feeding it a split directly.

```
    Function deptSheets() As Sheets
        Dim deptSheetsStr As String
        deptSheetsStr = "Sheet1" & "," & "Sheet2" & "," & "Sheet3" & "," & "Sheet4"
        
        Dim sheetArray As Variant
        sheetArray = Split(deptSheetsStr, ",")
        
        
        Set deptSheets = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetArray)
    End Function
```

The resulting deptSheets object allows me to loop through the sheets as I desired

```
For Each wks In lib.deptSheets
    Debug.Print wks.Name
Next
```

Comment: `arr` contains the exact same contents as `sheetArray`... this step is redundant. That said, I'd probably use a `Collection` here. Using a string of sheet names is a bit hacky.

Comment: You're correct about the arr being redundant, I have removed that. I don't know why it wasn't working as is. It really must have just been a malformed string and declaring deptSheets() as an Object instead of Sheets. I'll look into collections as I'm not too familiar with those. Thanks again.